# How to correctly accept Polar/LDPC encoded bits with PSK modulation?

Tags: modulation, demodulation, gnuradio, polar, ldpc

I have implemented a packet reception and transmission scheme using QPSK. Next I decided to add Polar/LDPC encoding. As a result, nothing is written to the received file.
I think the thing is that I'm unpacking the bits incorrectly after demodulation.
For convenience, in the diagram, I highlighted packet formation and encoding in blue, and decoding and unpacking in red.
[image]
I've tried many different versions of Repack Bits, not one has helped.

A similar problem exists for LDPC.

**Please tell me how to properly unpack the bits after demodulation?**

P.S. If I remove the signal modulation, then the flowchart will work (i.e. if I leave only the blue and red rectangle).

P.S.S. As I understood Polar and LDPC encoding works with MSB bits. Unfortunately, this is not explicitly stated on the Gnu Radio website.

Comment: hi! Asking three questions in 30 minutes might be a bit … much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi.
I just tried to solve these problems on my own about two weeks, but I reached the limit at which I don't understand where to go next. Therefore, the questions accumulated and I posted them.

Comment: Welcome, in any case :) It's absolutely welcome that you ask questions. It's just that I wanted to warn you that the number of people that have time to go through them is quite limited, and it might take some time till we read all three.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Yes, I understand that. Moreover, my questions are quite highly specialized and even a small hint is already good.

Comment: can i ask what is the output file when stream crc32 is set to check crc

Comment: I now have a flow graph successfully output through ldpc and qpsk, but once the noise is increased, I can’t receive anything. I’m currently thinking that the frame header is also affected when passing through the channel, and the receiving end cannot correctly identify the frame header. In the end the received data is also not recognized.

Comment: @qqqqqz Please do not post questions as answers to other questions. If you have a new question, please click the [`Ask Question`](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top of the page and ask your question as a separate one.

Comment: Did you ask this question on GNU Radio mailing list?